# How to pass param from middleware to controller

Tags: go, go-echo

I am building a web API with Echo Labstack framework. I have a middleware in my route to check for user authentication, but then I am having difficulty in passing the data to controller and could not find anything about this in Google and SO.

routes.go

```
func Routes(e *echo.Echo) {
    e.(middlewareAuthorise)
    user := e.Group("/user")
    user.GET("/profile", controllers.UserProfile)
}

func middlewareAuthorise(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        // Do some authentication here with access token and get user ID
        auth := controllers.Auth(c, 1)
        if auth["status"] != 200 {
            return c.JSON(401, map[string]any{"status": 401})
        }

        user_id := auth["user_id"]
        // I want to pass user_id to my controllers
        return next(c, user_id)
    }
}
```

contollers.go

```
func UserProfile(c echo.Context) error {
    // I want to get the user_id here from middleware
    return c.JSON(200, map[string]any{
        "user_id": user_id,
    })
}
```

I have searched and tried several combinations for a whole day but couldn't find something that works. How do I pass the param from middleware to my controllers in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: Thank you so much it works! Didn't know that context had such method. Please put it as an answer and I'll accept it right away sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the context's [`Set`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4#Context.Set) and [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4#Context.Get) methods.